# Editing VSDX (Visio 2013) in SharePoint 2010

Tags: document-library, visio

How do I get SharePoint 2010 to edit Visio 2013 documents? I currently get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
The document could not be opened for editing.  A Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application could not be found to edit the document.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I currently have it configured as follows in my DOCICON.XML:

```
<Mapping Key="vsdx" Value="icvsdx.gif" EditText="Microsoft Visio" OpenControl="SharePoint.OpenDocuments" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You properly need to add the filetype as a MIME type to your web front end's IIS

Open IIS, click on your WFE, double-click MIME types, click Add... under Actions and enter the below as

File name extension: vsdx

MIME type: application/vnd.visio

Repeat on all WFE's and perform an IISRESET

Would have shown you a screenshot of it, but I'm too new...